# Meaning of the phrase "discard credits"

Tags: meaning

Kindly explain the second part of the sentence.

> Inspectors are very serious about enforcing this, and keep a close eye on daily bread **discard credits** in the system.
>
> — [Saurin Patel](https://www.quora.com/profile/Saurin-Patel-4) on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-do-restaurants-do-with-uneaten-bread-in-the-bread-basket)

I looked through this page, *[Meaning of "credits"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45086/meaning-of-credits)*, but I am not sure how to make further research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term gets its meaning from the context of the source you referenced: a part of the particular management system used by Subway restaurant franchises.

A restaurant's profit or loss is determined in part by the cost of raw ingredients, in relation to the total sales receipts for all the food that is ultimately sold. Anytime something must be discarded instead of being sold, it reduces the profitability.

Apparently, Subway's management system makes allowances when bread is discarded, to offset the loss by compensating the franchise operator with some sort of credit. By doing this, it encourages the operator to always use freshly baked bread, and thus, maintain a consistent quality in all store locations.

So, as your example sentence says, the franchise inspectors look at the "**discard credits**" in the management reports as a way to see that the store is following the rules, and discarding a certain amount of unused bread each day.

Answer (score 2):

I think the sentence above should be written like

> Inspectors are very serious about enforcing this, and keep a close eye
>   on daily bread **and** discard credits in the system.

Now you can better visualize the meaning.Here the writer wants to tell that inspectors are very strict to make the franchisees follow the terms mentioned in the manual Subway has given to them.Inspectors keep the close eye on daily bread which is being baked by franchisees.The bread baked at night must be consumed till 10:30 AM and for lunch time bread should be baked again.If inspectors find that franchisee is not doing the same then they **discard the credits** given to them by Subway.Here **credits** may mean something like points or may be cash credit or whatever as per Subway's system.Discarded credits may result in losses for franchisees or it may affect differently.